# Auto Hide The Same Element Whenever It Becomes Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, hide

here is my problem.
The user can hover different type of objects.
Whenever he/she hovers the object an html in generated(depending on the type of that object) and injected into the innerHtml of a div element. Afterwards the visibility of that element is set to visible.

```
var tooltip = $("#tooltip")[0]; // Declared globally.

function showTooltip(innerHtml) {
    tooltip.innerHTML = innerHtml;
    tooltip.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Whenever the user moves the cursor away or to an other object, the visibility is set to hidden.
The main problem is, that whenever the user hovers an object, and does not move the mouse away, the tooltip should close automatically after 5 seconds.

```
<div id="tooltip" style="position:absolute; z-index: 50;  visibility:hidden"></div>
```

As a solution I have added this code at the end of showTooltip method:

```
if(timeoutHandler != null) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
}

timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
    if(timeoutHandler !== null) {
        tooltip.style.visibility = "hidden";
        timeoutHandler = null;
    }
}, 5000);
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Kindly put your "hover" codes into the question

Comment: What is the problem? The tooltip stays visible? If so, in which case?

Comment: @ConnorsFan the question is, how to hide the tooltip whenever it becomes visible, without using a timer?

Comment: Using a timer looks to me like the correct way to do it.

Comment: ok thanks @ConnorsFan